# User Lockout in .net 4.5.1 ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

So in the new .Net Framework 4.5.1 AspNetUser table does not have a column to lock user out after a finite number of unsuccessful attempts. Are there frameworks or solutions built for that purpose to replace the functionality that once existed in previous .net frameworks? Or do I have to build my own?

Answer (score 31):

In the upcoming 2.0 Identity release, there is support for Account Lockout

Configuration:

```
    manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true; // Enables ability to lockout for users when created
    manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;
```

Usage:

```
manager.IsLockedOutAsync(user.Id) // Check for lockout
manager.ResetAccessFailedCountAsync(user.Id); // Clear failed count after success
manager.AccessFailedAsync(user.Id); // Record a failure (this will lockout if enabled)
manager.SetLockoutEnabled(user.Id, enabled) // Enables or disables lockout for a user
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense if the methods had an overload that accepted a username? (at this point in the logic I typically have a username, I will only get the userid after a successful login)

Comment: Add this point you can (should?) deal with your user object. Prior to do any login checks you can just verify is the user extists first (var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);) and then deal with whatever scenario you want if the user is not null.