# How to implement account lockout in custom forms authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, custom-authentication

I started a project using MVC and I started off with an empty project, I should not have started it off as an empty project because, now I have to implement authentication and I am going to need to use custom forms authentication because I am not sure how to implement the ASP.NET Identity into the project. Since I am using custom forms authentication, how do I set up an account lockout after 3 attempts? I know I could easily just keep count of the attempts with a buttonclick event if I was using webforms. Should I do the same thing in this project as I would with webforms? Next time I do a project with MVC I won't start off with an empty project.

Comment: Can you give a bit more information about your authentication methods? If you are using ASP.NET Identity 2, this comes out of the box - you'll just need to configure it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22483316/user-lockout-in-net-4-5-1-asp-net-mvc-5 for more info.

Comment: @hbulens, I am not using ASP.NET Identity 2, because I started the project off as an empty MVC project and it wasn't added. I don't know how to add it now that I had already started the project, so thats why I am creating custom forms for it

Comment: The fastest and best way is to make learn ASP.NET Identity, laziness won't bring you anywhere farther... there are plenty of ways how to import .net Identity in an existing project, the package is available at nuget, see https://www.talkingdotnet.com/add-identity-ui-asp-net-core-2-1-application/

Answer (score 0):

By simply installing the nuget package you'll have this up and running in no time. You'll save yourself a lot of time. If you do want to continue with your custom way, you could keep a counter per username and increment it each time login fails and then prevent user from logging in if the locking number has been exceeded. Still, it will take you a few days to complete this feature (even then, prone to bugs and hackers).